# How to receive a string properly from UART

Tags: c, string, buffer, pic, uart

I sending a string like this: 
$13,-14,283,4,-4,17,6,-240,-180#

But is not showing up because the buffer is 'overloading', how can I receive the whole string or how can I clear it after each byte read?

```c
// get a character string 
char *getsU2(char *s, int len) { 
    char *p = s; // copy the buffer pointer 
    do {
        *s = getU2(); // get a new character 
        if (( *s=='\r') || (*s=='\n')) // end of line... 
            break; // end the loop s++;

        // increment the buffer pointer 
        len--;
    } while (len>1); // until buffer is full 

    *s = '\0'; // null terminate the string 

    return p; // return buffer pointer
} 


// get a character string
char *getsU2(char *s, int len) { 
    char *p = s; // copy the buffer pointer 
    do {
        *s = getU2(); // get a new character 

        if (( *s=='\r') || (*s=='\n')) // end of line... 
            break; // end the loop 

        s++;     

        // increment the buffer pointer 
        len--; 
    } while (len>1); // until buffer is full

    *s = '\0'; // null terminate the string      

    return p;    // return buffer pointer
}



char getU2(void) { 
if(U2STAbits.OERR == 1) 
{     U2STAbits.OERR = 0; } 
while (!U2STAbits.URXDA);    // wait for new character to arrive return U2RXREG;
                             // read character from the receive buffer }

getsU2(buffer,sizeof(buffer));
```

Comment: Please get familiar with indentation (made an edit for you), choose yourself a good coding style.

Comment: Is this for a microcontroller? When do you get the error about "buffer overloading"?

Comment: It looks like the getU2 code fragment may be incomplete. I dot not see a return statement. What is the declaration of the "buffer" variable?

Comment: You're not reading from the U2RXREG anywhere in the code snippet provided - you will need to in order to process the incoming UART bytes.

Comment: Also the microchip documentation states: "The data in the receive FIFO should be read prior to clearing the OERR bit. The FIFO is reset when OERR is cleared, which causes all data in the buffer to be lost" (see: https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/70232C.pdf) so this could be another reason why you don't have any data in the register

Answer (score 4):

Try using the UART receive interrupt.  Code below is for a PIC24H; modify appropriately.

In your init function:

```
IFS0bits.U1RXIF = 0;        // clear rx interrupt flag
IFS0bits.U1TXIF = 0;        // clear tx interrupt flag

IEC0bits.U1RXIE = 1;        // enable Rx interrupts
IPC2bits.U1RXIP = 1;
IEC0bits.U1TXIE = 1;        // enable tx interrupts
IPC3bits.U1TXIP = 1;
```

Create an interrupt handler that places the bytes into a buffer or queue:

```
void __attribute__((__interrupt__, auto_psv)) _U1RXInterrupt(void)
{
    char bReceived;

    // Receive Data Ready
    // there is a 4 byte hardware Rx fifo, so we must be sure to get all read bytes    
    while (U1STAbits.URXDA)
    {
        bReceived = U1RXREG;

        // only usethe data if there was no error
        if ((U1STAbits.PERR == 0) && (U1STAbits.FERR == 0))
        {
             // Put your data into a queue
             FIFOPut(bReceived);

        }

    }    

    IFS0bits.U1RXIF = 0;        // clear rx interrupt flag 
}
```

Your queue code is along these lines:

```
#define FIFO_SIZE 64

char pbBuffer[FIFO_SIZE];
char *pbPut;
char *pbGet;

void FIFOInit(void)
{
    pbPut = pbBuffer;
    pbGet = pbBuffer;
}

void FIFOPut(char bInput)
{
    *pbPut = bInput;
    pbPut++;

    if (pbPut >= (pbBuffer + FIFO_SIZE))
        pbPut = pbBuffer;
}

char FIFOGet(void)
{
    char bReturn;

    bReturn = *pbGet;
    pbGet++;

    if (pbGet>= (pbBuffer + FIFO_SIZE))
        pbGet= pbBuffer;
}
```

Obviously, one should beef up the FIFO functions to prevent overflow, return errors on an empty queue, etc.

Comment: Also, you should add the volatile keyword on any variable that is shared between an interrupt and normal code.  (not an issue here because the variable pbBuffer is never edited, but speaking generally)

Comment: Great answer! I would also suggest to anyone else coming across this in future to reference the appropriate Microchip UART documentation. E.g. for PIC24H see: https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/70232C.pdf